# Peer certificate with Node.js Express on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate, serverless

With a classic Node.js Express server, the client browser certificate is available with `req.connection.getPeerCertificate()`. But `aws-serverless-express` doesn't fill all request properties (cf `https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/blob/ac6ebd1e9faacbe0381b66d06ece6aa72d0cd007/src/index.js#L41`).

How can I access to the peer certificate in an Express app running in an AWS Lambda ?